# Jest can't resolve project paths in react app

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

So, I am learning to use jest with react-testing-library in a project I am working on. Here is the code of the component I am testing:

```
//DefaultLayout.js

import React, { Component, Suspense } from 'react';
import Header from 'components/Header/Header.js'

...
```

And then the test file:

```
//DefaultLayout.test.js

import React from 'react'
import { render, cleanup } from "@testing-library/react"
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import DefaultLayout from "./DefaultLayout.js"

...
```

Now, when I run `npm test` I get this:

```
Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'components/Header/Header.js' from 'DefaultLayout.js'

      2 | import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
      3 | import * as router from 'react-router-dom';
    > 4 | import Header from 'components/Header/Header.js'
        | ^
```

Now, to make that import work I have a `jsconfig.json` file like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

All folders, including `components` are in the `src` directory. I know jest is not importing this configuration, and that I need to set this up again for jest. I just don't understand how to do it.

I created a `jest.conf` file, but it's not working:

```
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "<rootDir>/src"
  },
}
```

That is my latest try. The jest.conf file is in the root dir of the project.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

I replaced the jest.conf file for a `jest.config.js` file:

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"]
};
```

and then I just run jest and it works.